# Note application that uses IMAP protocol

Tags: software-recommendation, sync, macosx, notes, imap

I'm looking for an note app that uses IMAP protocol so I can sync the notes that I have created on my Google account using Apple Devices. I'm using Ubuntu Mate and Linux Mint. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin for Thunderbird, specifically for iOS IMAP Notes:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/ios-imap-notes/

[image]

Installation:

1. Download and save the file to your hard disk.
2. In Mozilla Thunderbird, open Add-ons from the Tools menu.
3. From the options button next to the add-on search field, select "Install Add-on From File..." and locate the downloaded add-on.

Comment: It does install with Thunderbird 61 if you edit _install.rdf_, but it does not save notes on a server :(