# Read / Edit iPhone (iOS) using IMAP notes on Linux

Tags: apple, notes, imap, ios

I am looking for a way to read / edit iOS Notes on Linux.

Technically, iOS devices can be configured to store the notes on a IMAP account. That will create a "Notes" directory on the IMAP account where each email is treated as one note.

I was wondering if there is any Linux GUI application that can deal with this so I can manage my iOS notes on linux as well. Reading them with a Email client is not a problem. The editing is a bit of a problem with email clients.

Comment: Why not just go to iCloud.com and edit them there?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/809775/note-application-that-uses-imap-protocol